# How to configure logstash and filebeat SSL communication

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

### The question:

Can someone help me figure out why I can't get filebeats to talk to logstash over TLS/SSL?

### The Error:

I can get the filebeat and logstash to talk to eachover with TLS/SSL disabled, but when i enable it and use the settings/config below, I get the following error (observed in `logstash.log`):

```ruby
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-28T17:21:44.445000+0100", :message=>"Pipeline aborted due to error",
 :exception=>java.lang.NullPointerException, :backtrace=>["org.logstash.netty.PrivateKeyCo
nverter.generatePkcs8(org/logstash/netty/PrivateKeyConverter.java:43)", "org.logstash.nett
y.PrivateKeyConverter.convert(org/logstash/netty/PrivateKeyConverter.java:39)", "java.lang
.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)", "RUBY.create_server(/usr/share
/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-beats-3.1.0.beta4-java/lib/logstash/
inputs/beats.rb:139)", "RUBY.register(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/log
stash-input-beats-3.1.0.beta4-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:132)", "RUBY.start_inputs(
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:311)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.eac
h(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", "RUBY.start_inputs(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/li
b/logstash/pipeline.rb:310)", "RUBY.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/lo
gstash/pipeline.rb:187)", "RUBY.run(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipelin
e.rb:145)", "RUBY.start_pipeline(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:2
40)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"], :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-28T17:21:47.452000+0100", :message=>"stopping pipeline", :id=>"main"
, :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-28T17:21:47.456000+0100", :message=>"An unexpected error occurred!",
:error=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `stop' for nil:NilClass>, :backtrace=>["/us
r/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-beats-3.1.0.beta4-java/lib/lo
gstash/inputs/beats.rb:173:in `stop'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/inp
uts/base.rb:88:in `do_stop'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/usr/share/logst
ash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:366:in `shutdown'", "/usr/share/logstash/logsta
sh-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:252:in `stop_pipeline'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/
lib/logstash/agent.rb:261:in `shutdown_pipelines'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each
'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:261:in `shutdown_pipelines'",
 "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:123:in `shutdown'", "/usr/share/
logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:237:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vend
or/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/share/logsta
sh/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:157:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/
jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bo
otstrap/environment.rb:66:in `(root)'"], :level=>:fatal}
```

### The Setup:

#### Servers

- 2 servers.

  > **$> uname -a**
  >   Linux elkserver 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 10 23:08:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  >   **$> cat /etc/*-release**
  >   CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
- SELinux is Permissive (soz).
- Firewalls are of. (mazza soz).
- One server runs `elasticsearch` and `logstash`; one runs `filebeat`.

#### Elasticsearch

> **$> /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -version**
>   Version: 2.4.1, Build: c67dc32/2016-09-27T18:57:55Z, JVM: 1.8.0_111

#### Logstash

> **$> /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -V**
>   logstash 5.0.0-alpha5

#### Filbeat

> **$> /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -version**
>   filebeat version 5.0.0 (amd64), libbeat 5.0.0

### Config:

- Logstash

> ```
> input {
>   beats {
>     port => 5044
>   ssl => true
>   ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/filebeat-forwarder.crt"
>   ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/filebeat-forwarder.key"
>   }
> }
> output {
>   elasticsearch {
>   hosts => "localhost:9200"
>   manage_template => false
>   index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
>   document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
>   }
> }
> ```

- Filebeat.yml

> ```
> output:
>  logstash:
>    enabled: true
>    hosts:
>      - "<my ip address>:5044"
>    timeout: 15
>    tls:
>      certificate_authorities:
>      - /etc/pki/tls/certs/filebeat-forwarder.crt
> filebeat:
>  prospectors:
>    -
>      paths:
>        - /var/log/syslog
>        - /var/log/auth.log
>      document_type: syslog
>    -
>      paths:
>        - /var/log/nginx/access.log
>      document_type: nginx-access
> ```

- File: `openssl_extras.cnf`:

  ```
  [req]    
  distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name    
  x509_extensions = v3_req    
  prompt = no    
  [req_distinguished_name]    
  C = TG    
  ST = Togo    
  L =  Lome    
  O = Private company    
  CN = *    
  [v3_req]    
  subjectKeyIdentifier = hash    
  authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer    
  basicConstraints = CA:TRUE    
  subjectAltName = @alt_names        
  [alt_names]    
  DNS.1 = *    
  DNS.2 = *.*    
  DNS.3 = *.*.*    
  DNS.4 = *.*.*.*    
  DNS.5 = *.*.*.*.*    
  DNS.6 = *.*.*.*.*.*    
  DNS.7 = *.*.*.*.*.*.*    
  IP.1 = <my ip address>
  ```

The command used to create the cert:

> $> openssl req -subj '/CN=elkserver.system.local/' -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl_extras.cnf \
>       -x509 -days 3650 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/filebeat-forwarder.key \
>       -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/filebeat-forwarder.crt

Comment: ***`CN=elkserver.system.local`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Comment: @jww- thanks and sorry. CN was actually being set by an Ansible variable so to clean up my examples I removed the templating formatting that ansible uses. I suspect my 'guess' at the ansible variable `ansible_fqdn` was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Filebeat 5.0 the `tls` configuration setting was changed to `ssl` to be consistent with the configuration setting used in Logstash and Elasticsearch. Try updating your Filebeat configuration.

References:

- [Securing Communication With Logstash by Using SSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ssl-logstash.html#configuring-ssl-logstash)
- [Breaking Changes in 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/breaking-changes-5.0.html#_configuration_file_changes)